# Logging structured key-value pairs in springboot with slf4j over log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, log4j2, slf4j

I'm working on a Kotlin spring-boot project that is using slf4j over log4j2 and I would like to log in a key-value way in order to add filters based on the keys to the data analyzer (splunk) I'm using.

According the slf4j [docs](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) that should be possible using the fluent-api but that is only available from the version 2.0.0 and the project is using 1.7.30 and I was unable to figure it out how to update it.

Now I'm just logging with a plain string like following:

```
log.info("My log")
```

I was reading that the output should be in a JSON format but I don't know what to configure and how to make that possible.

Any ideas about how solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: with Kotlin Strings you could just inline the values or insert a Map into your String. I know its not really what you asked for, but for Kotlin there is a nice little library you can use: https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/wiki. Also

Comment: @Dinosaur-Guy the important thing is the data analyzer being able to recognize the key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

**Remark:** Spring Boot offers you 3 logging APIs out-of-the-box: `java.util.logging`, SLF4J and Log4j2 API. To exploit the full power of Log4j2 Core (without loosing any data if you decide to switch to Logback), you should use the last one.

The solution mostly depends upon the relationship between the key/value pairs and the message being logged.

If their are not related to the message, but give the message a context, use the [`ThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/package-summary.html):

```java
try (Instance c = CloseableThreadContext.put("userId", ...)
        .put("requestId", ...)
        .put("otherData", ...)) {
    ...
    log.info("Message");
}
```

If the message itself is a map, use a [`StringMapMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/StringMapMessage.html):

```java
log.info(StringMapMessage.newInstance(map));
```

If you use Log4j2 Core, you can log both maps as JSON using the [JSON template layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html). The `ThreadContext` can be logged using the `mdc` resolver, while the `MapMessage` using the `map` or `message` resolvers, e.g.:

```json
{
  "tags": {
    "$resolver": "mdc"
  },
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "message"
  }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#map-resolver-template) for details.

**Edit:** If your main purpose is filtering and classifying, you can also use [markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html). These are not key/value pairs, but a way to split the domain of all your logs into subdomains.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer ! I was able to make the output in a json format like this 

{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1674943339,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 800911000
  },
  "message" : "{foo=bar, module=testModule}",
}

If you look at the "message" property the value is generated with logger.info(myMap) but I'm not sure if the data analyzer will recognize it, I was expecting something like:
{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1674943339,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 800911000
  },
  "foo" : "bar",
  "module": "testModule"
}

Comment: Your `message` has been serialized as string, you probably set `stringified` to `true`. If you want certain keys to appear as properties of the top JSON object, you need to provide a `key` property to the resolver.

Comment: `provide a key property to the resolver.` Could you pls expand on that @PiotrP.Karwasz, with an example code? I'm stuck on this part making the message treated as a JSON instead of string-version of it

Comment: Also, I had to change `log.info(StringMapMessage.newInstance(map));` to `org.slf4j.Logger.log.info(m.newInstance(Map.of()));` but even then it's a compilation error for me `Cannot resolve method 'info(StringMapMessage)'`. Would you happen to know how to address this?

Comment: @CyriacGeorge: you are using SLF4J instead of the Log4j API. Your logger needs to be of class `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. Regarding the parameters available for the `map` and `message` resolvers, look at the examples on the [documentation page](https://s.apache.org/1tpzy)

Comment: You are correct. For the benefit of others, this is what worked for me.
LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json
```
"message": {
    "$resolver": "message",
    "stringified": false
  }
```
dependencies
```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json'
```
Java
All logs will be logged in JSON style. Additionally, if we log a Map e.x. `log.info(Map.of())` the log message itself is treated as a JSON